# System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'No se puede encontrar la columna '

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net

Estoy tratando de guardar datos en Visual Studio con VB.Net y al momento de guardar sale `System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'No se puede encontrar la columna 6.'`

Este es el código

```
Private Sub btnGuardar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGuardar.Click   
    Dim odr As DataRow
    If nuevo Then
        odr = ods.Tables("CLIENTE").NewRow
    Else
        odr = ods.Tables("CLIENTE").Rows(pos)
    End If
    odr(1) = txtCODIGO.Text
    odr(2) = txtDNI.Text
    odr(3) = txtNOMBRE.Text
    odr(4) = txtAPELLIDOS.Text
    odr(5) = txtTELEFONO.Text
    odr(6) = txtGENERO.Text
    If nuevo Then
        ods.Tables("CLIENTE").Rows.Add(odr)
    End If
    oda.Update(ods, "CLIENTE")
    Form1_Load(sender, e)
    HabilitarBotones(True)

End Sub
```

Comment: si estas seguro que tenes 6 columnas, entonces el problema es que tenes mal enumeradas las columnas porque como todo array el primer indice es el 0, entonces tu columna 6, debes enumararla como 5, y tu primera columna es la 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estas seguro que tenes 6 columnas, entonces el problema es que tenes mal enumeradas las columnas porque como todo array el primer indice es el 0, entonces tu columna 6, debes enumararla como 5, y tu primera columna es la 0.

```
Private Sub btnGuardar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGuardar.Click
    Dim odr As DataRow
    If nuevo Then
        odr = ods.Tables("CLIENTE").NewRow
    Else
        odr = ods.Tables("CLIENTE").Rows(pos)
    End If
    odr(0) = txtCODIGO.Text
    odr(1) = txtDNI.Text
    odr(2) = txtNOMBRE.Text
    odr(3) = txtAPELLIDOS.Text
    odr(4) = txtTELEFONO.Text
    odr(5) = txtGENERO.Text
    If nuevo Then
        ods.Tables("CLIENTE").Rows.Add(odr)
    End If
    oda.Update(ods, "CLIENTE")
    Form1_Load(sender, e)
    HabilitarBotones(True)
```